# C++ terminal server for existing terminal client protocol

Tags: c++, sockets, terminal

I want to communicate with a C++ simulated UART which is communicating with a (simulated) guest Linux system terminal.

What I have is a callback called when receiving character outputs from the UART, and a method I can call to send characters to this same UART.

I'd like to be able to connect to this UART with my host terminal, implementing a server socket communicating using an existing protocol.

What protocol should I use to keep a high compatibility? I'm thinking about telnet. Are there existing frameworks in C++ or C to implement that quick and easy?

Comment: What about TCP? A TCP server socket would [accept](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) normal TCP sockets, and you could forward data streams just as are from UART to socket(s?) and vice versa.

Comment: That's probably the solution.